# If $a - b = 3$, $a + b + x = 2$, then find the value of $(a - b)[x^3 - 2ax^2 + a^2x - (a + b)b^2]$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

After solving the question I got to the conclusion that it has something to do with $(a-b)$ being a factor of the whole polynomial. And since the value of $(a-b)$ is already given we can further solve the equations to get the value of $a$,$b$ and $x$ and substitute the values obtained to find the answer. But I am stuck on finding the value of x using the fact that $(a-b)$ is a factor.
If anyone knows the answer please share it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=(a-b)[x^3-2ax^2+a^2x-(a+b)b^2]$. Now using the Remainder Theorem, which tells us that if you divide a polynomial $f(x)$ by $(x-y)$ then the remainder is $f(y)$. Now, we know that $(a-b)$ is a factor of $f(x)$ so $x=3$ is a root. Substituting it in $a+b+x=2$ we get $$a+b+3=2$$ $$\implies a+b=-1$$ Now add $a-b=3$ and $a+b=-1$ getting $$a-b+a+b=3-1$$ $$\implies 2a=2$$ $$\implies a = 1$$. Now substitute the value of $a$ in $a-b=3$ we get $b=-2$. Now putting all these three values in $f(x)$, we get
$$f(x)=(1-(-2))[3^3-2\times 1 \times 3^2 + 1^2 \times 3 - (1-2)(-2)^2]$$
$$=(1+2)[27-18+3-(-4)]$$
$$=3(27-18+3+4)$$
$$=3(34-18)$$
$$=3 \times 16$$
$$=48$$
Hence the value of $f(x)$ is $48$

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution it helped a lot! But I am having a doubt, can you please elaborate on how you concluded that x=3 is a root?

Comment: @AnubhavKumar, let $f(x)=(a-b)[x^3-2ax^2+a^2x-(a+b)b^2] \dots (1)$ be are equation 1, and Euclid's Division Lemma i.e $a=bq+r \dots (2)$ be our second equation. Then if we find the relation between (1) and (2) we can observe that we are dividing $f(x)$ by $(a-b)$ and getting remainder $0$. We know the value of $(a-b)$ to be $3$ which means that on dividing $f(x)$ by $x-3$, remainder will be come $0$ as $3$ is a factor of $f(x)$, so we conclude that $x=3$ is a root of $f(x)$. Consider accepting the answer if it helped you :)